# Upload de imagem usando GWT

Tags: gwt

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o framework GWT e surgiu a necessidade de fazer uploads de imagens para que as mesmas sejam salvas num banco de dados. Gostaria que alguém me mostrasse algum exemplo que realmente funcione e/ou como devo proceder para realizar tal tarefa.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema. Utilizei as bibliotecas do Apache Commomn. Pra quem tiver encontrado a mesma dificuldade que eu, aqui está o link da página do projeto.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo utilizar as novas funcionalidades que o XMLHTTPRequest2 está trazendo.
Um framework GWT que já encapsula estas funcionalidades é o Crux Framework, dê uma olhada nele:
http://www.cruxframework.org/
Veja o componente "File Uploader":
http://showcase.cruxframework.org/

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, Samuel Cardoso. Consegui resolver o problema usando as bibliotecas do Apache Commons. Estou usando o framework Extjs.